# Any good file renaming scheme?

Tags: file-upload, file-rename

I'm trying to find good ideas to rename files.

I have a small site with some editors and sometimes they upload files with the same name of a previous file. For example:

> document.doc

I don't like the solution:

> document(1).doc

Because it says nothing about the file, only that there was other 'similar' file before.

I thought to add a timestamp but it is not nice to download a file:

> document_1348849299.doc

Do you have any suggestions or a really great way to name files?

Comment: filename + timestamp. Do it. That is the best way to avoid errors of files with the same names. If you want to preserve the original file names (such as when they are being downloaded) keep a database table of onDisk file names (just time stamps) and display file names.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to change the file names on the fly? It means, after users click the link?

Answer (score 0):

I think you approach is a good one. You could format the timestamp to be a bit more attractive e.g. document_2012-09-28_11.59.00.doc

An alternative would be to keep a database table with files and a table with file versions. Name the file on disk after the file version id.

e.g. SQL Tables

```
File
    FileID
    FileName
    CreatedBy
    [Whatever]
FileVersion
    FileVersionID
    FileID
    UserName
    UploadTime
    [Whatever]


~/file_store/
    1.file
    2.file
```